# python pyserial read data and respond

Tags: python, pyserial

I am trying to open a serial port connection and keep it open as long as data if communicating. I also want to respond if certain data is received. Below is an example of the python script. I am able to open the serial port send data and the script responds, it will not respond with the elif data. 
I am new to pyserial and have been working on python lately but not great by any means.

Thank you

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', timeout=10)  # open serial port
print(ser.name)         # check which port was really used
response =  ser.read()
if response == (b'\r'):
    ser.write (b'ID=')
elif response == (b'\r\r\x1bPG1\r'):
    ser.write (b'110 1.8<CR><ACK><CR><ESC>[p<CR>')
#time.sleep(5)
#print ()
#ser.close()             # close port
```

Comment: please restate as a specific question

Comment: How do I receive '\r' respond with 'ID=' then wait to receive '\r\r\x1bPG1\r' and respond with '110 1.8<CR><ACK><CR><ESC>[p<CR>' . After I respond with the 'ID=' my session closes